# LESS.js Not Loading?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm attempting to use LESS but even after following along with tutorials, the page fails to render. Previously I had a few dozen different classes in the body class="" tag, but for the sake of cleanliness, I want to use LESS to encapsulate it in a single class.
 
It hasn't loaded in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox
 
All of the classes I use within the .LESS file are included in the .CSS

index.html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index_files/site.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="./index_files/site.less"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.0/less.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body class="main_body"> 
   ...
</body>
```

site.LESS:

```
@import (less) "site.css";

main_body {
  .site-spacing-custom;
  .site-outer-padding-large;
  .site-alignment-center;
  .tweak-site-ajax-loading-enable;
  .ancillary-header-full-width;
  .tweak-header-cart-style-text;
  .show-site-footer;
}
```

After hosting the page via my laptop, it's now rendering but the .LESS code isn't working at all:
[image]

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: Maybe just the dot at main_body is missing? `.main_body { ... }`

Comment: no go on the dot :(

Comment: Added console errors to post. Seems to be an error with the less.js.min somehow?

Comment: You need to use a webserver instead of loading your site from `file://`.  Loading a page from `file://` only works for very simple pages.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server - To make it easy, `npm install` this. Then execute `http-server` from inside your development directory (granted you have NodeJS installed).

Comment: @Amy It's running but now it refuses to acknowledge the .less code

Comment: What does "refuses to acknowledge" mean?  Did you follow the instructions at http://lesscss.org/usage/

Comment: You very likely need to include the javascript file *before* the .less file.

Comment: @Amy I double checked, and yes I'm following the usage as far as I can see. I saw "Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.", so that seems to be correct as well. By refusing to acknowledge, I meant that it's treating the classes as undefined, despite them being (supposedly) imported from the .css file

Comment: even when pre-compiling via the `lessc` command, it's throwing `NameError: .site-spacing-custom is undefined`